# Incoherent return message after username check

Tags: php, sql

I'm new here so I hope I do this right.
I am having some problems with sending the right message from my php to my 
html.

Here you can see the php part that sould give a message back if the username isn't valid(if is uses #$%^& etc.)

```
$validUsername = $CurrentUser->ValidateUsername($username);

//if the input isn't filled send a message back
    if(!$validUsername)
{
    $messageError = "Please fill in a valid username";
    header("location: ../public/index.php?messageError=$messageError");
}
```

and another one that should check if the username is unique

```
    $uniqueUsername = $CurrentUser->CheckAvailableUsername($validUsername);

    if (!$uniqueUsername)
{
    $messageError = "Please fill in a unique username";
    header("location: ../public/index.php?messageError=$messageError");
}
```

now the weird thing is if use #$%^&etc. as a username it will give me back a please fill in a unique username instead of please fill in a valid username and I can't find out why.

oh btw I made a class named User with these methods Ill show them below here.

```
        public function ValidateUsername($username)
    {
        if (!empty($username))
        {
            if (isset($username))
            {
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $username))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return $this->username = $username;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And the other one.

```
        public function CheckAvailableUsername($username)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_todolist`
            WHERE `username` = '$username';";

        $result = $this->dataBase->query($sql)->rowCount();
        if ($result == 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return $this->username = $username;
    }
```

I really hope you guys can help me with this.

Comment: What is the order of operations, ie. what gets called first?

Comment: The order is as displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `header(...);` you need to throw in a `return;` or `exit;` to exit right there, otherwise it continues beyond that header.

**Additional Notes**

You are open to SQL injection in `CheckAvailableUsername`, you need to sanitize the value before you get to that function and also escape/[bind](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) the value to your query instead. It looks like you are using PDO already.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback about the sql injection and for solving my problem.